# Running 240v generator inlet and 240v house power outlet in the same conduit?

Tags: receptacle, conduit, generator

I'm simultaneously installing a 50A NEMA 14-50 outlet in the garage (for ev charging) and running a line for a portable generator from just outside the garage, back to the panel. I'll be using PVC conduit between the panel and the garage.

The generator line will come into a new [transfer switch](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Reliance-306LRK-6-Circuit-Transfer-Switch-Kit-P2/50436688) where I'll have six selected household circuits.

My question is, can I run all the necessary thhn lines through the same conduit? Is is wrong to have multiple same-colored load and neutral lines in the same conduit?

I've read [this post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/150418/running-circuit-and-generator-hookup-in-same-conduit) which is very similar but both runs are 110v.  Also, the principle response says that the same ground can be used for both circuits but since in this case I'm using the switching subpanel I'm not sure if it still applies.

Comment: How many amps are you running on the line from the generator, and how large were you planning your conduit to be?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel.  30 amps/240v.   I understand that I'd need 8 thhn.  The  4 for the outlet would be 6 awg.  The generator input could be 10 awg but I might oversize to 6, allowing a bigger generator someday. So 1 1/4 conduit should suffice.  I'm curious, is my amperage and conduit size relevant to my question? Not that I mind any commentary and additional advice.

Comment: You need to review NEC 225.30. You can not have multiple feeders to the out building.

Comment: @EdBeal it's not an out building, it's an attached garage.

Comment: @EdBeal Is a generator inlet circuit considered a feeder? For what it's worth, I did do a 240 feeder from house to detached garage and a 240 generator inlet circuit from garage back to house as described in the question. Inspector didn't raise any objections (2017 NEC). One anecdote doesn't mean code allows it though; possibly it's disallowed but my inspector didn't notice or chose to overlook it.

Comment: The short answer is yes that's allowed (702.10 in 2017 NEC). But if you'll share more details such as photos of your existing panel we'll try to persuade you to use an interlock kit rather than the Reliance panel and we'll help size the wiring and conduit (derates may require conductor up-sizing for example).

Comment: Yes, really. Those Reliance panels have many safety issues, and only support 6 circuits. Why not support any circuit for 1/3 the price, and have your MWBCs be safe, and your surge, GFCI and AFCI all work?

Comment: @GregHill, thanks for the specific NEC reference.  If you want to post that as an answer you can collect the credits for it.  I can certainly be persuaded to ditch the Reliance panel and go directly to the main panel, using an interlock.  I was just a little wary  of that, because of certain discussions about the shared neutral being a danger, which I initially thought the Reliance panel would address, but after reviewing its installation instructions I see that it does not address that issue.   So: I shouldn't worry about the shared neutral?  .

Comment: Ok I was thinking a detached building, in my jurisdiction there can be only 1 service, this sounded like a the feeder was going back to the home and a line for the garage from the home. I would strongly suggest as others have feeding a main panel with an interlock kit and not the +300$ reliance, I have never had or seen any safety problems with those. a simple interlock kit and Double pole breaker for the inlet cost less & allows you to upsize to your generator size if you install big wire now, reliance you are limited to the switches that take much more $ in wiring to install $$$ modify later

Comment: @ElroyFlynn -- what make and model is your generator?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Champion "9375".  true model number 100219.  What are you trying to ascertain?

Comment: @ElroyFlynn -- whether the generator's netural is floating or bonded, as that'll determine what transfer hardware to use

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel ah, thanks for that.  This link says that "Most Champion Power Equipment generators have a floating neutral " but the same page gives instructions on how to convert from bonded to floating. When used through my house panel, I'd want floating neutral, right? http://help.championpowerequipment.com/article/4etN4HzYKq-disconnecting-the-neutral-bond-to-frame

Comment: @ElroyFlynn do you want to be able to take the generator out and use it as a portable should the need arise, or are you dedicating it to powering your house? According to [its manual](https://www.championpowerequipment.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/100219-om-english.pdf), it has a bonded neutral, btw

Comment: It's for the house.  I would un-bond the neutral, as described by Champion.  I would tag it prominently that it would need to be re-bonded if used as a portable.

Answer (score 2):

### Interlock beats 6-8-10 circuit transfer switch

Neither one handles neutral separate from ground, so you make no progress on that front.

However both work OK with a "floating neutral" generator. You'll want to bond that neutral if you use it as a portable generator.

The interlock lets you throw over your whole panel, removing the need to choose circuits at install time.  It works same as a 2-pole "big knife switch" style transfer switch, except that the big 200A side is handled by the breaker you already paid for. The $30-70 sliding plate links it with a $12 backfeed breaker, so together they function as a "DPDT center off" switch i.e. big knife switch.

What the interlock does with neutral makes it play well with panel features such as MWBC*, GFCI and AFCI.  You must choose circuits so you don't overload the breaker, but you're free to do that "on the fly".

---

The way the "6-8-10s" handle neutral is appalling, and ripped right out of the 1960s mentality of wiring. They didn't think about generator isolation nor about overloading MWBCs*, and their method *precludes* usage with an AFCI or GFCI breaker.  It's a complete gong show.  These problems come up *a lot*, which is the reason for our disdain - we don't like people spending $300+ and then having this much trouble.   In most cases, send it back with a vengeance.  Or sell it on Craigslist to someone who needs it.

They do have applicability in a minority of panels, which are too obsolete to be well supported with interlocks, or whose design precludes an interlock (the otherwise *excellent* Pushmatic).  However, such older panels tend to be stacked with MWBCs, and those cannot be safely/legally connected to a 6-8-10 type (unless put on a ganged switch, as they must throw together), and that forces you to use 2 of your circuits, when you probably only want one side of that MWBC.

So yes, if you can find a suitable interlock for that panel, it's a fantastic way to go, and a real money-safer to boot.

### A feeder and a circuit in the same conduit

This is legit.  It's a bit easier to see that it's legit when the feeders are going to the same panel, so that's a tick in favor of "interlock".

### 2 circuits in the pipe causes a *thermal derate*, though

Having 2 circuits in the same conduit/raceway means they must *both* be "de-rated" to 80% of their insulation rating (which is 90C for most wire and cable types).

[image]

Take #6 aluminum (or #8 copper) THHN. Assuming our terminals at both ends are rated 75C/aluminum, that wire is good for 50A if it were alone in the conduit.

However, with two circuits (4 conductors that count for thermal derate purposes) apply an 80% derate, of the maximum insulation rating of that wire.   THHN is 90C wire, and is allowed 55A @ 90C.  We derate that 80% and we're down to 44A.   *Well, that stinks!*

Likewise #6 copper and #4 aluminum - normally 65A @ 75C thermal, but they derate got 80% of 75A == 60A with 2 circuits in the pipe.

### Notes on EV installation

A 50A outlet is a "starter setup" for EVs.  Down the road you may want more, so I might as well tell you now.

EVSE is the awkward word for "the charging equipment on the wall".

First, in NEC 2020 jurisdictions, a NEMA 14-50 socket requires GFCI protection. **You do not want that**.  Why not? Because the EVSE equipment *already has a much better GFCI in it*.  First, the internal controls aren't on GFCI so they stay up. Second, UL has approved this GFCI *to automatically re-close* - if it trips, it will make several attempts through the night to self-reset.  Since most "nuisance trips" are momentary events that clear themselves, this means you awaken to a charged car not a tripped GFCI. General purpose GFCIs *can't* do that.  So in some locations, if you have a socket you are married to a useless, redundant GFCI.   The solution is to *hard-wire* the EVSE.

If you don't want to rewire because you're using the "thrown-in" mini EVSE that came with the car, that one is really intended to be carried around in the trunk for opportunity charging (sort of an EV version of jumper cables).  That will get "old" PDQ and you'll wish for a wall-mounted version.  Look for a "Share2 enabled" EVSE, which has the hardware support for "power sharing" with a second EVSE.  That is the next state-of-the-art. Note that Tesla Wall Connector V2 and V3 have that - and are bargain priced at $500, but need a $100 adapter to charge non-Teslas.

Share2 calls for connected EVSEs, that share a single allocation of power (reasonably close to what your EV feeder can permit). Say you have 80A to provision, you tell the EVSE "master" that, and it coordinates with the Share2-enabled EVSE's to make sure load doesn't exceed that. They communicate with the cars to work that out.  **

So if it were me, I would "pencil in" the idea of running three #2 aluminum to a 120V/240V subpanel.  **I would size conduit for that**. That is good to 80A (because of our derate, ouch) and will support the foreseeable future in EV charging, plus a couple 120V circuits for lights and receptacles too.

---

---

---

* A *Multi-Wire Branch Circuit*, or MWBC, is a circuit typically run on /3 cable.  It has 2 hot wires (red and black) sharing a neutral.  It's a way to economize on wire. The hot wires must be placed on opposite phases to prevent the neutral from being overloaded.  These tend to be a mess in older panels. The handles must also be tied, so that a maintainer is switching off the whole circuit (and doesn't get "bit" by current trying to move on the neutral.).

** How does a car listen to the EVSE? The EVSE puts a square wave on the Control Pilot pin. The duty cycle maps to the max amps the car may draw. The car's internal charger takes it from there.  How does the EVSE listen to the car? It has a current sensor so it knows what the car is drawing.  So the EVSE can see the car is only drawing 21A, and change the Control Pilot signal to authorize only 21A, and give the rest back to the pool.

Comment: Thanks for the great details and advice.  Based on this advice, I do plan to ditch the  6-8-10 and go directly to the panel with interlock.  

You suggest that I consider "running three #2 aluminum to a 120V/240V subpanel.".   Three, because the two circuits could share a neutral?  Or ground?

Comment: FYI, in that great response there are a couple of possible typos, unless I misunderstand.  I mention it because maybe this is text that you copy and reuse. 

1. "we must take 80% off the maximum insulation rating of that wire."
s/b "we must take 80% of the maximum insulation rating of that wire."
2. "Having 2 circuits in the same panel means..."
s/b "Having 2 circuits in the same conduit/raceway means..."

Comment: @ElroyFlynn Thank you for the corrections, fixed.  Yes, my argument is in favor of a subpanel.  It's *possible* to have a 240V-only subpanel with no neutral and no 120V loads, and that would suffice solely for EV charging. However, it's a matter of time before someone tries to slap a 120V load in there, so it's safer to bring neutral. Neutral can be downsized, but the rules are a PITA and it invites inspector battles, so I say "size conduit for full size neutral".  Of course both feeders we're discussing will be grounded too.